# Subject not found when creating new schema in schema registry error code 40401

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

```
[2023-05-30 14:11:39,104] INFO 10.237.87.231 - - [30/May/2023:14:11:39 +0000] "GET /subjects/MY_TOPIC-key/versions/latest HTTP/1.1" 404 68 "-" "Java/11.0.17" 2 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests)
[2023-05-30 14:11:39,109] INFO Registering new schema: subject MY_TOPIC-key, version null, id null, type null, schema size 177 (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.SubjectVersionsResource)
[2023-05-30 14:11:39,118] INFO 10.237.87.231 - - [30/May/2023:14:11:39 +0000] "POST /subjects/MY_TOPIC-key/versions?normalize=false HTTP/1.1" 200 11 "-" "Java/11.0.17" 10 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests)
[2023-05-30 14:11:39,120] ERROR Request Failed with exception  (io.confluent.rest.exceptions.DebuggableExceptionMapper)
io.confluent.rest.exceptions.RestNotFoundException: Subject 'MY_TOPIC-key' not found.
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.exceptions.Errors.subjectNotFoundException(Errors.java:77)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.SubjectVersionsResource.getSchemaByVersion(SubjectVersionsResource.java:141)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
```

I want to register new schema using akhq GUI but I got error subject not found. I don't understand this error.  Why subject should exist when I want to create new schema ?

**UPDATE**

I tried to create it with curl:

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" -k --data @key http://my-custom-schemaregistry.org/subjects/MY_TOPIC-value/versions?normalize=false

it return id of schema 123 but when I tried to GET :

http://my-custom-schemaregistry.org/schemas/ids/123

I got:

```
{"error_code":40403,"message":"Schema 123 not found"}
```

**UPDATE2**

in logs I can see new schema:

```
[2023-05-30 21:37:26,752] INFO Registering new schema: subject TEST_TEMP, version null, id null, type null, schema size 756 (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.SubjectVersionsResource)
[2023-05-30 21:37:26,765] INFO 10.237.87.231 - - [30/May/2023:21:37:26 +0000] "POST /subjects/TEST_TEMP/versions?normalize=false HTTP/1.1" 200 11 "-" "Java/11.0.17" 14 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests)
[2023-05-30 21:37:26,766] ERROR Request Failed with exception  (io.confluent.rest.exceptions.DebuggableExceptionMapper)
io.confluent.rest.exceptions.RestNotFoundException: Subject 'TEST_TEMP' not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why subject should exist when I want to create new schema

Because you are posting a *new version* to a subject, even if that is the first version.

You can see from `"GET /subjects/MY_TOPIC-key/versions/latest HTTP/1.1" 404` that it has to first lookup the latest version before it can register, in order for the registry to perform backwards-compatibility checks

You should ignore these logs for the first registered version. You cannot disable them on the server.

Comment: how I can ignore this logs when this return schema registry and not create new schema ?

Comment: see update even I create new schema with curl and got id in response I can not find this schema

Comment: Sounds like you are running multiple instances of the registry behind a load balancer? Try sending a request to one at a time, manually

Comment: nope I can see it in logs in UPDATE2

Comment: Have you tried manually sending the API requests without AKHQ? I personally don't use it, so cannot reproduce your issues

Comment: yes in question you can see curl commands

Comment: @hudi the CURL cmd you mentioned is correct, it should work and if not, then did you find any solution?